# Minikube volume write permissions?

Tags: kubernetes, permissions, minikube, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

The big picture is: I'm trying to install WordPress with plugins in Kubernetes, for development in Minikube.

I want to use the official wp-cli Docker image to install the plugins. I am trying to use a write-enabled persistence volume. In Minikube, I turn on the mount to minikube cluster with command:

```
minikube mount ./src/plugins:/data/plugins
```

Now, the PV definition looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
    name: wordpress-install-plugins-pv
    labels:
        app: wordpress
        env: dev
spec:
    capacity:
        storage: 5Gi
    storageClassName: ""
    volumeMode: Filesystem
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
    hostPath:
        path: /data/plugins
```

The PVC looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
    name: wordpress-install-plugins-pvc
    labels:
        app: wordpress
spec:
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce    
    resources:
        requests:
            storage: 5Gi
    storageClassName: ""
    volumeName: wordpress-install-plugins-pv
```

Both the creation and the binding are succesful. The Job definition for plugin installation looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
    name: install-plugins
    labels:
        env: dev
        app: wordpress
spec:
    template:
        spec:
            securityContext:
              fsGroup: 82 # www-data
            volumes:
                - name: plugins-volume
                  persistentVolumeClaim:
                       claimName: wordpress-install-plugins-pvc                
                - name: config-volume
                  configMap:
                       name: wordpress-plugins
            containers:
            - name: wpcli
              image: wordpress:cli
              volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: "/configmap"
                name: config-volume
              - mountPath: "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins"
                name: plugins-volume
              command: ["sh", "-c", "id; \
                                     touch /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test; \
                                     ls -al /var/www/html/wp-content; \
                                     wp core download --skip-content --force && \
                                     wp config create --dbhost=mysql \
                                                      --dbname=$MYSQL_DATABASE \
                                                      --dbuser=$MYSQL_USER \
                                                      --dbpass=$MYSQL_PASSWORD && \
                                     cat /configmap/wp-plugins.txt | xargs -I % wp plugin install % --activate" ]
              env:
                  - name: MYSQL_USER
                    valueFrom:
                        secretKeyRef:
                            name: mysql-secrets
                            key: username
                  - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
                    valueFrom:
                        secretKeyRef:
                            name: mysql-secrets
                            key: password
                  - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
                    valueFrom:
                        secretKeyRef:
                            name: mysql-secrets
                            key: dbname
            restartPolicy: Never
    backoffLimit: 3
```

Again, the creation looks fine and all the steps look fine. The problem I have is that apparently the permissions to the mounted volume do not allow the current user to write to the folder. Here's the log contents:

```
uid=82(www-data) gid=82(www-data) groups=82(www-data)
touch: /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test: Permission denied
total 9
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Mar  1 20:15 .
drwxrwxrwx    3 www-data www-data      4096 Mar  1 20:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000            64 Mar  1 17:15 plugins
Downloading WordPress 5.3.2 (en_US)...
md5 hash verified: 380d41ad22c97bd4fc08b19a4eb97403
Success: WordPress downloaded.
Success: Generated 'wp-config.php' file.
Installing WooCommerce (3.9.2)
Downloading installation package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/woocommerce.3.9.2.zip...
Unpacking the package...
Warning: Could not create directory.
Warning: The 'woocommerce' plugin could not be found.
Error: No plugins installed.
```

Am I doing something wrong? I tried different `minikube mount` options, but nothing really helped! Did anyone run into this issue with minikube?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked deeper into the way the volume mount works in minikube, and I think I came up with solution.

## TL;DR

```
minikube mount ./src/plugins:/data/mnt/plugins --uid 82 --gid 82
```

## Explanataion

There are to mounting moments:

- minikube mounting the directory with `minikube mount`
- volumne being mounted in Kubernetes

`minikube mount` sets up the directory in the VM with the UID and GID provided as parameters, with the default being `docker` user and group.

When the volume is being mounted in the Pod as a directory, it gets mounted with the **exact same** UID and GID as the host one! You can see this in my question:

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000            64 Mar  1 17:15 plugins
```

UID=1000 and GID=1000 refer to the `docker` UID and GID in the minikube host. Which gave me an idea, that I should try mounting with the UID and GID of the user in the Pod.

82 is the id of both the user and the group `www-data` in the `wordpress:cli` Docker image, and it works!

One last think worth mentioning: the volume is mounted as a subdirectory in the Pod (`wp-content` in my case). It turned out that `wp-cli` actually needs access to that directory as well to create temporary folder. What I ended up doing is adding an `emptyDir` volume, like this:

```
volumes
  - name: content
    emptyDir: {}
```

I hope it help anybody! For what it's worth, my version of minikube is 1.7.3, running on OS X with VirtualBox driver.

Comment: It's a good temporary solution. However this forces to always take care manually of the mount and has other bugs that can happen (especially with symlinks: see [minikube#9757](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9757). The actual correct solution is to configure a Security Context and use `runAsUser` & `runAsGroup` as [mentioned by @Wytrzymały Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60486541/3088045)

Answer (score 7):

This is a long-term issue that prevents a non-root user to write to a container when mounting a `hostPath` PersistentVolume in Minikube.

There are two common workarounds:

1. Simply use the root user.
2. [Configure a Security Context for a Pod or Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) using `runAsUser`, `runAsGroup` and `fsGroup`. You can find a detailed info with an example in the link provided.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm reluctant to using root user for security reasons. I found a minikube-specific workaround (I think it's a workaround, at least). I'm describing it in a separate response!

Comment: Hi! Can you show an example, how to do it correctly, please?
Tried different values for `runAsUser` etc, still get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, for Minikube today, 2 (Configure a Security Context for a Pod or Container using runAsUser, runAsGroup and fsGroup. You can find a detailed info with an example in the link provided.) doesn't seem to be a viable option, because the HostPast provisioner, which is used under the hood, doesn't honor Security Context. There seems to be a newer HostPath Provisioner, which preemptively sets new mounts to 777, but the one that came with my 1.25 MiniKube is still returning these paths as 755.

Answer (score 0):

I am deploying a daemonset which mounts the hostpath-provisioner directory and sets all subdirs to 777 every second. Obviously not great, but I prefer this workaround since it is self-contained to the minikube cluster (no mounting shennanigans), and it is not as intrusive as messing with the provisioner addons (which may or may not work anyways).

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: minikube-pv-hack
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: minikube-pv-hack
  namespace: minikube-pv-hack
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: minikube-pv-hack
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: minikube-pv-hack
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      containers:
      - name: minikube-pv-hack
        image: registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8:latest
        command:
        - bash
        - -c
        - |
          while : ; do
            chmod 777 /target/*
            sleep 1
          done
        volumeMounts:
        - name: host-vol
          mountPath: /target
      volumes:
      - name: host-vol
        hostPath:
          path: /tmp/hostpath-provisioner/default
```