# Apache Flink - Mount Volume to Job Pod

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-batch

I am using the WordCountProg from the tutorial on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_flink/apache_flink_creating_application.htm . The code is as follows:

**WordCountProg.java**

```
package main.java.spendreport;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;

public class WordCountProg {

       // *************************************************************************
       // PROGRAM
       // *************************************************************************
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
          // set up the execution environment
          final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
          // make parameters available in the web interface
          env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(params);
          // get input data
          DataSet<String> text = env.readTextFile(params.get("input"));
          DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts =
          // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
          text.flatMap(new Tokenizer())
          // group by the tuple field "0" and sum up tuple field "1"
          .groupBy(0)
          .sum(1);
          // emit result
          if (params.has("output")) {
             counts.writeAsCsv(params.get("output"), "\n", " ");
             // execute program
             env.execute("WordCount Example");
          } else {
             System.out.println("Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.");
             counts.print();
          }
       }
       
       // *************************************************************************
       // USER FUNCTIONS
       // *************************************************************************
       public static final class Tokenizer implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
          public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {
             // normalize and split the line
             String[] tokens = value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
             // emit the pairs
             for (String token : tokens) {
                if (token.length() > 0) {
                   out.collect(new Tuple2<>(token, 1));
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

This example takes in a text file as input, provides a count for how many times a word appears on the document, and writes the results to an output file.

I am creating my Job Image using the following Dockerfile:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM flink:1.13.0-scala_2.11
WORKDIR /opt/flink/usrlib
# Create Directory for Input/Output
RUN mkdir /opt/flink/resources
COPY target/wordcount-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/flink/usrlib/wordcount.jar
```

Then the yaml for my job looks as follows:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: flink-jobmanager
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flink
        component: jobmanager
    spec:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      containers:
        - name: jobmanager
          image: docker/wordcount:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          env:
          #command: ["ls"]
          args: ["standalone-job", "--job-classname", "main.java.spendreport.WordCountProg", "-input", "/opt/flink/resources/READ.txt", "-output", "/opt/flink/resources/results.txt"] #, <optional arguments>, <job arguments>] # optional arguments: ["--job-id", "<job id>", "--fromSavepoint", "/path/to/savepoint", "--allowNonRestoredState"]
          #args: ["standalone-job", "--job-classname", "org.sense.flink.examples.stream.tpch.TPCHQuery03"] #, <optional arguments>, <job arguments>] # optional arguments: ["--job-id", "<job id>", "--fromSavepoint", "/path/to/savepoint", "--allowNonRestoredState"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6123
              name: rpc
            - containerPort: 6124
              name: blob-server
            - containerPort: 8081
              name: webui
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 6123
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 60
          volumeMounts:
            - name: job-artifacts-volume
              mountPath: /opt/flink/resources
            - name: flink-config-volume
              mountPath: /opt/flink/conf
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 9999  # refers to user _flink_ from official flink image, change if necessary
      volumes:
        - name: flink-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: flink-config
            items:
              - key: flink-conf.yaml
                path: flink-conf.yaml
              - key: log4j-console.properties
                path: log4j-console.properties
        - name: job-artifacts-volume
          hostPath:
          # directory location on host
            path: /Users/my-user/Documents/semafor/apache_flink/PV
```

The goal is to mount /Users/my-user/Documents/semafor/apache_flink/PV where there is a READ.txt file into the pod that serves as input to the job. But when the job tries to execute, I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /opt/flink/resources/READ.txt does not exist or the user running Flink ('flink') has insufficient permissions to access it.
```

I have tried to run:

```
sudo chown -R 9999:9999 /Users/my-user/Documents/semafor/apache_flink/PV
```

Also ran chmod 777... but I get the same error.

I also tried copying the jar to where the READ.txt file is: */Users/my-user/Documents/semafor/apache_flink/PV* on my local directory and mount that to /opt/flink/usrlib instead, but then I got:

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not find the provided job class (main.java.spendreport.WordCountProg) in the user lib directory (/opt/flink/usrlib).
```

I am not that experienced in Kubernetes or Flink, so I'm not sure if I am mounting incorrectly or if I'm doing something wrong. If you have any suggestions, please lmk. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try creating a dir /tmp/flink on the host and mounting it in your pod. If it works, then it is a permission issue

Comment: @RakeshGupta I tried it, but I still get: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /tmp/resources/READ.txt does not exist or the user running Flink ('flink') has insufficient permissions to access it. It's like the hostPath is not mounted at all.

Comment: Where are you creating the host volume? Master node?

Comment: I am using minikube on my local machine, so yes. I've also tried PVs but same issue. Perhaps I'm not understanding how these work. If I mount a directory on my local as a PV, I was expecting for files that are in that directory to be accessible by the pods that have a claim to that PV, and whatever files the pods place on that PV, I should see it on my local. This does not appear to be the case.

Comment: If using minikube you need to first mount the volume using
minikube mount /Users/my-user/Documents/semafor/apache_flink/PV:/tmp/PV

Then use /tmp/PV in your hostPath configuration in the volumes section

Refer to these threads:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682114/hostpath-with-minikube-kubernetes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60479594/minikube-volume-write-permissions

Comment: That was the issue. I realize now that Minikube creates the cluster on a VM, and such VM does not have access to my local directories unless I mount them. Thank you for your help @RakeshGupta . Feel free to add your comment above as an answer to this question and I'll accept it as the solution.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using minikube you need to first mount the volume using

```
minikube mount /Users/my-user/Documents/semafor/apache_flink/PV:/tmp/PV
```

Then use /tmp/PV in your hostPath configuration in the volumes section

**Refer to these threads:**
[Minikube volume write permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60479594/minikube-volume-write-permissions)

[HostPath with minikube - Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682114/hostpath-with-minikube-kubernetes)